# How do install Cloud Manager on my Mac?

Tags: bash

I've cloned the repository on GitHub and I'm looking for installation instructions.

So far, I've done these steps (in Mac Terminal):

1. cd /opt
2. git clone https://github.com/cldmgr/cloud-manager.git
3. cd cloud-manager

Now what?

Answer (score 1):

What you've done so far is perfect!

Before running the installer, add /opt/cloud-manager to your PATH variable.  For Bash, you would add following like to the bottom the .bash_profile file in your home directory:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/cloud-manager
```

The next step is to run the installer, which will ask you a bunch of questions about your infrastructure in order to configure Cloud Manager (CM).

NOTE: you should be logged in as the user account you intend to run CM under prior to performing the installation - including the 'git clone' command.

Here's how to start the interview:

```
$ ./methods/cm-install
```

It'll look like this:

```
## Welcome to Cloud Manager (CM) Installer
This installer was launched because CM could not find a configuration file
and/or Ansible inventory file where expected. The following interview will
prompt you for all information needed to configure CM.

After the interview, you'll be prompted to save your answers to a response file. This is convenient in the event you want to re-configure CM without answering all the (annoying) questions again.

To do so, run "./methods/cm-init -r templates/<your_responseFile>"

## Configuring CM Core Server

Enter hostname/ip for the CM control node [localhost]:
--> accepted: localhost

Master Private Key (managed server access) [keys/master/cm-master]:
--> accepted: keys/master/cm-master

Master Public Key (managed server access) [keys/master/cm-master.pub]:
--> accepted: keys/master/cm-master.pub

Master User Account [cmadmin]:
--> accepted: cmadmin

Master Password - Cleartext [null-disallowed]:
--> accepted: ********

...
```

At the end of the interview it will ask you to save your response file.  I recommend that you do, as it will save you time later -- in the event you want to reset everything back to defaults as you're learning to use CM.

To re-run the installer using the response file, run:

```
$ ./methods/cm-init -c -r templates/your-response-file.resp
```

Now that CM is configured, just type 'cm' to see the usage statement:

```
$ cm
Usage: cm [<options>] <method> [args]

[methods]
Configuration:
  group <add|remove|addAttr|removeAttr|addRule|removeRule> [args]
  ipam <subnet|range|checkout|checkin> [args]

Infrastructure:
  create [-s][-f] <hostname> <group> [args]
  createN [-s|-r] <clusterName> <N> <hostnameBase> <group> [args]
  configure [-s] <hostname> [args]
  deploy [-s] <hostname> <playbookName> [args]
  power [-s] <on|off|cycle> [args]
  decommission [-s] [-h <hostname>|all]
       [-g <groupName>]
       [-c <clusterName>]
  reprovision [-s] <hostname>

Continuous Integration:
  dso [-s] <name> <ansible|chef|puppet|cm> [args]
  pipeline <add|remove|addAttr|removeAttr> [args]

System:
  show <server|group|job|subnet|subnetMap|cluster> [args]
  connect <hostname> [args]
  system <vboxCli|encrypt> [args]
  runScript <scriptName>
  runCmd <hostname> <command>

[options]
  -s : show standard output from ansible playbook
  -x : show extended help
```